# are supercolumns of a row all from same node

Tags: storage, cassandra

I have a super columnfamily, each row will have thousands of supercolumns. My question is, if I do a query against a row, will all supercolumns of the row be returned from the same node. So in general, it's more of question of whether the whole data of any given row of a cassandra column family be stored as whole. I do understand that different rows of the column family might from different nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"All data for a single row must fit (on disk) on a single machine in the cluster. Because row keys alone are used to determine the nodes responsible for replicating their data, the amount of data associated with a single key has this upper bound."

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

Comment: cool, that make sense - just one call needed (to one single node) to fetch the data of a row. the node to direct the call to is deducted from the given row key.

Answer (score 2):

Super column families work the same as column families.  If you have a replication factor of N, then eventually N machines will store an entire copy of that row, which means all the columns and super columns.

Comment: so each of the N machine will have the full copy of the code.

Comment: each of N machines will have the full row eventually.  when reading you have to take the read consistency_level into account as well.  if you read at consistency level ONE, you only contact one node, if you read at consistency level QUORUM, the read will go to all N nodes, and wait until a quorum of them respond.